# The main view's height is changing between viewControllers. How should I keep them the same?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am creating an app with a UITabBarController at top level with navigation controllers as its children. When I transition to the first screen from a tab, the frame of VC.view is (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 618.0) and then when I segue to another VC, VC.view's frame for that VC is (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0). Since the difference is 49, I am assuming this is because the TabBar's height is taken into account the first time around but does not apply this further down the stack. I use a proportional constraints based on these numbers. Is there any option so it will always remove the tabBar height or an option that will always not remove the height. I just want a setup where every main VC's view height is equal.

Placing this in viewDidLoad() of all descendant VCs fixes my problem:

```
let size = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - tabBarController!.tabBar.frame.height)
view.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
```

but this feels hacky to me and would prefer a toggled option or setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using storyboards or xibs, make sure the constraint for the view's bottom is pinned to the `view` instead of `bottom layout guide`. It should work perfectly well.

[image]

Comment: I am not referring to any views I create, but the top level view for each UIViewController.

Comment: @Sethmr if so, make sure you measure the view height after all of its subviews finished their layout in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, update your constraints there

Comment: That is exactly where I printed the frame values. I am pretty iOS Savvy.... I just didn't want to hack this together if I was missing something.

Comment: The problem I am facing is that my proportionally placed logo is not in the same place on both views during a UIViewControllerContextTransitioning transition. I could just make them animate to each others frames, but that is not the desired look for the App.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your viewcontroller view outlet and update the height frame accordingly. or You can add subView and adjust its height accordingly either using constraint

Comment: I can do this, but is there not just some option that can fix this? I find that at the most generic level, There should be symmetry between the ViewControllers that are used. If I have to set the view's frame based on the UIScreen height minus the tab bar, that is more or less a hack to me.